# Simple PHP Routing Class

Tags: php, .htaccess

Im trying to build a routing class on a PHP project, but i'm wondering what the best way of approaching things is.

The project's folder-structure looks like this:

```
[example.com]
index.php
.htaccess

[router]
-router.php

[db]
-db connection.php

[includes]
home.php
about.php
login.php
```

In my .htaccess file I've got all traffic redirected to index.php like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
RewriteEngine On
```

Index.php uses a router class to detect the request and provide the appropriate content.

```
<?php
require 'router/Route.php';
require 'router/Router.php';

Router::map(Router::HTTP_METHOD_GET, '/login', function() {

    include 'includes/login.php';

});

?>
```

However i'm running into problems with ajax requests within the pages themselves, as well as chained PHP includes. My router seems to block the requests.

Is there a super simple routing solution I can use to simply serve files, and allow chained PHP `includess` in those files?

Comment: can you also paste your index.php file. See what you are doing there.

Comment: I just added it, the problem I'm having is that all the routers i've tried block ajax requests.

Comment: Is AJAX request using GET or POST?